# Socket.io custom events slow to be received by server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a very basic socket.io client built in node following their chat room tutorial which works fantastic. I can send messages and they get received on the other client instantly.

When adding a "this user is typing" functionality, I added a custom event to the socket.

**Client.js**

```
let io = require('socket.io-client')
let socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080')

let typing = document.getElementById('typing')
let messages = document.getElementById('messages')
let form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]
let input = document.getElementById('m')


socket.on('typing', function (isTyping) {
  if (isTyping) {
    typing.style.visibility = 'visible'
  } else {
    typing.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  }
})

socket.on('message', function (msg) {
  messages.innerHTML += `<li>${msg.from} : ${msg.message}</li>`
})

// Add a chat message submission
form.onsubmit = function (a) {
  a.preventDefault()
  socket.emit('message', input.value)

  // Reset typing
  input.value = ''
  input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
}

// Add a typing event
let isTyping = false

input.addEventListener('input', function () {
  if (this.value && !isTyping) {
    isTyping = true
    socket.emit('typing', true)
  } else if (!this.value && isTyping) {
    isTyping = false
    socket.emit('typing', false)
  }
})
```

**Server.js**

```
let socketio = require('socket.io')

let app = require('express')()
let http = require('http').createServer(app)
let io = socketio(http)

let server = http.listen(process.env.PORT || '8080', () => {
    let address = server.address()
    console.log(`Listening on ${address.address}:${address.port}`)
})

io.on('connection', function (socket) {  

    console.log('a user connected')

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('a user disconnected')
    })

    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
        io.emit('message', { from: socket.nickname, message: msg })
    })

    socket.on('typing', function (isTyping) {
        console.log('typing')
        socket.broadcast.emit('typing', isTyping)
    })
})
```

When the user starts typing (i confirm that the emit function is called with a console log), the event is not received by the server for possibly upwards of 10s or even longer. I confirm this by another console log.

`Type -> Client console logs out -> *wait seconds+* -> Server console logs out`

This is strange to me as the message function is almost instant, I assume as this is a native event. I have tried using `io.emit` too which makes no difference.

I do notice that as I push events through, it forces older ones to complete (but not the newer ones). I type, nothing happens, stop typing, and the type event suddenly emits server side. I feel this is the key to debugging what is happening but I cannot figure out why it would do this.

Comment: Do you get an unusual number of `a user connected` messages?  I'm wondering if client and server are properly connected?  A mismatched client and server version of socket.io can cause bad connections that resort to polling.

Comment: Nope, I am monitoring the connects/disconnects and I get one as I expect.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue now